# Disable brightness changes while buffering html5 video

Tags: javascript, html

In chrome, while buffering, the video brightness is unchanged meanwhile on firefox there is a brightness fadeOut while buffering (but the video is still played). When the video is fully loaded the brightness is back to normal.

Is there a way to disable this fadeIn/fadeOut ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was firefox 44.0, the problem is solved on firefox 45.0